# Cordova build fails with file not found, but file exists

Tags: node.js, cordova, windows-8

```
C:\Users\jamiller\Desktop\magicCarpetApp\platforms\windows8\cordova\lib>ls
WindowsStoreAppUtils  build.js  clean.js  deploy.js  log.js  target-list.js

C:\Users\jamiller\Desktop\magicCarpetApp\platforms\windows8\cordova\lib>cordova build windows8
Running command: C:\Users\jamiller\Desktop\magicCarpetApp\platforms\windows8\cordova\build.bat

Building Cordova Windows 8 Project:
        Configuration : Debug
        Directory : C:\Users\jamiller\Desktop\magicCarpetApp\platforms\windows8
C:\Users\jamiller\Desktop\magicCarpetApp\platforms\windows8\cordova\lib\build.js(57, 5)     WshShell.Exec: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on? It's failing on an error saying that build.js doesn't exist, but it clearly does. The permissions on it are fine as well and I should have full access to it.

Comment: It's actually saying on line 57, char 5 in `build.js` there is a file reference not found.

Comment: Yea just noticed that. Following the suggestions here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/133

But now I have a new problem: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4bdrhS9N

Comment: try removing the semicolon from the end of the path